# Computing the exponential generating function.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $f(n)$ be the number of ordered set partitions of $[n]$. An ordered set partition is a sequence $S_1, \dots , S_k$ of disjoint non-empty subsets whose union is $[n]$. Compute the exponential generating function for $f(n)$.

Comment: We are not here to do your homework for you.  Please show a minimum of effort in describing what you have tried and where you are having trouble.

Comment: @JairTaylor I am sorry this has come out this way. I am taking a combinatoric class and I am quite lost. I am not looking for a straight answer. It would be great to help me with this question.

Comment: @RonaldSanchez you might want to explore the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences for help/insight with this and other combinatorics problems: https://oeis.org/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By definition, $f(0)=0$. We also need the recurrence relation
$$ f(n+1) = \sum \limits_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} f(k) $$
for $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$, which is derived [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431688/bell-numbers-number-of-partitions-of-set-of-cardinality-n-recurrence-relation). If we denote the exponential generating function by $g$, we find
\begin{align}
g(x) &= \sum \limits_{m=0}^\infty \frac{f(m)}{m!} x^m = 1 + \sum \limits_{n =0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} f(n+1) \\
&= 1 + \sum \limits_{n =0}^\infty \int \limits_0^x \frac{y^n}{n!} \,  \mathrm{d} y \sum \limits_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} f(k) = 1 + \int \limits_0^x \sum \limits_{n =0}^\infty \sum \limits_{k=0}^n \frac{y^n}{n!}   {n \choose k} f(k) \, \mathrm{d} y \\
&= 1 + \int \limits_0^x \sum \limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f(k)}{k!} y^k \sum \limits_{n=k}^\infty \frac{y^{n-k}}{(n-k)!} \, \mathbb{d} y = 1 + \int \limits_0^x \sum \limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f(k)}{k!} y^k \sum \limits_{l=0}^\infty \frac{y^l}{l!} \, \mathbb{d} y \\
&= 1 + \int \limits_0^x g(y) \mathrm{e}^y \, \mathbb{d} y \, .
\end{align}
Interchanging summation and integration is justified by Levi's monotone convergence theorem. Since $f(n) \leq n!$ holds for $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042398/bell-number-vs-factotial) question), the power series converges at least for $|x| < 1$. Now we only need to solve the above integral equation for $g$. Hint: A differential equation may be simpler.